# Converting JSON object to Array using JQ

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to convert map of objects to an array with jq

My Input is

```
{
  "fish-chips": {
    "likeDislikeRatio": ["80%", "20%"],
    "country": ["BRIT_FOOD","USA_FOOD"]
  },
  "sausage": {
    "likeDislikeRatio": ["75%", "25%"],
    "country": ["EU_FOOD"]
  },
  "cheese-burger": {
    "likeDislikeRatio": ["25%", "75%"],
    "country": [
      "BRIT_FOOD",
      "USA_FOOD",
      "EU_FOOD",
      "DEFAULT"
    ]
  }
}
```

And my expected output is

```
[
  {
"name" : "fish-chips",    
"likeDislikeRatio": [
      "80%",
      "20%"
    ],
    "country": [
      "BRIT_FOOD",
      "USA_FOOD"
    ]
  }
]
[
  {
"name" : "sausage",
    "likeDislikeRatio": [
      "75%",
      "25%"
    ],
    "country": [
      "EU_FOOD"
    ]
  }
]
[
  {
"name" : "cheese-burger",
    "likeDislikeRatio": [
      "25%",
      "75%"
    ],
    "country": [
      "BRIT_FOOD",
      "USA_FOOD",
      "EU_FOOD",
      "DEFAULT"
    ]
  }
]
```

**what I tried**
The closest filter I could find was **to_entries[] | [.key, .value]**

but the output is not as what I expected and I feel that there should be one more filter with this to get the desired out put

Current Output

```
[
  "fish-chips",
  {
    "likeDislikeRatio": [
      "80%",
      "20%"
    ],
    "country": [
      "BRIT_FOOD",
      "USA_FOOD"
    ]
  }
]
[
  "sausage",
  {
    "likeDislikeRatio": [
      "75%",
      "25%"
    ],
    "country": [
      "EU_FOOD"
    ]
  }
]
[
  "cheese-burger",
  {
    "likeDislikeRatio": [
      "25%",
      "75%"
    ],
    "country": [
      "BRIT_FOOD",
      "USA_FOOD",
      "EU_FOOD",
      "DEFAULT"
    ]
  }
]
```

I saw many posts on doing the opposite that is converting array to map using either reduce or INDEX but not what I expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close.

```
to_entries[] | [{name: .key} + .value]
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/bwxqWYFsDe)</sup>

Comment: I am not sure if the followup question can be asked. Is it possible to further have a filter and output has added text and filters like this

Comment: split_clients "${remote_addr}${http_user_agent}" $fish_chips_default {
  80%    "fish-chips=0";
  20%    "fish-chips=1";
}

split_clients "${remote_addr}${http_user_agent}" $sausage_default {
  25%    "sausage=0";
  75%    "sausage=1";
}

Comment: map $foodExpPage $foodexperiments {
  default $cheese_burger;
  "brit" '$cheese_burger,$fish_chips';
  "usa" $cheese_burger;
  "eu" '$sausage';
}

Comment: As you can see it has lots of character addition and replacement. Is this possible with further filters?

Comment: @SandeepNair I think you should post another question for that.

Comment: thanks once again. I create a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68437782/iterating-a-json-array-using-jq-and-transforming